# How do you change a pdf from black and white to a specific color?

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm in a bind and am trying to print without black ink. Some suggest doing this in a PC, but I'm on a Mac. Plus, I'd rather do this with an online operation that converts the file to something I can print.

Comment: Using black or color ink is up to the printer device driver, not the colors used in the document. Also, even color uses black ink.  Almost all printers use CYMK and not RGB for printing.  CYMK is Cyan, Yellow, Magenta, and (yes).. ***BLACK***.  I doubt you will get it to print.. sure the printer manufacturer could let you try.. but then you don't have to buy more ink (crack) from them.  I am not saying you will fail.. I am saying not very likely.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one website that takes a PDF, changes all the colors to a color you select, and then you can download it. It should work regardless of operating system (like on your Mac). It has limited colors, but some might work if you have, for example, cyan or magenta, or a combo of non-black ink. You could also try command line tools like ImageMagick++ or GIMP.

https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/